# issue with text file reading and emty space passing in dynamic array

Tags: c++, performance

I need help in c++ with reading text from file into dynamic array.

## File

```
Regbis 
Vardenis Paverdenis
Jonas Puikuolis
Gediminas Jonaitis

Futbolas 
Tadas Pilkius
Justas Julis

Tenisas 
Ricerdas Berankis
```

I tried like this and another way with `while` and `getline` s.empty but it didn't work for me.

```
using namespace std;
struct struktura{
char team;
char lastname;
char firstname;
} sarasas[999];

int main()
{
char x [200];
int kiek;
ifstream duomenys;
duomenys.open("duom.txt");
int row, col;
while (!duomenys.eof())
{
    cout << "How many teams" << endl;
        cin >> row;

    int **a = new int *[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cin >> col;
        a[i] = new int[col];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            duomenys >> a[i][j];
            cout << a[i][j] << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    }
    system("Pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: "It didn't work". Ok, but, can you tell us *how* it didn't work? What was the expected result, and what was the actual result?

Comment: I need read all this file when make buble or something so it would be in abc.. by sport and name
Sample 
Regbis (sport)

Gediminas Jonaitis(name lastname)  

Jonas Puikuolis()
Vardenis Pavardenis()

Comment: I try while(!duomenys.eof())
duomenys << sarasas[i].name;
while(getline(duomenys,s)&&s.emty()) also didnt worked main think cant get read normaly. Im new in this still learning and try find similar posts but to hard understand or didnt worked with my experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this has quite a few problems. I'd start with using `std::string` for the strings, and `std::vector` for the dynamic array.

Then I'd work at defining the data structures at least halfway reasonably. I think the general idea is something like this:

```
struct team { 
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> players;
};
```

Then I'd define an `operator>>` for a team, something like this:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, team &t) {
    std::vector<std::string> players;

    std::string temp;

    // If we can't read a team name, return signaling failure:
    if (!std::getline(is, temp))
        return is;

    // save the team name
    t.name = temp;
    // and read the player's names:
    while (std::getline(is, temp)) {
        if (temp.empty())  // empty line--end of this team's players
            break;      
        players.push_back(temp);
    }
    t.players = players; // Write the player's names into the destination
    is.clear(); // and signal success, since we read a team's data
    return is;
}
```

From there, we can read all the teams in a file:

```
std::ifstream in("teams.txt");

std::vector<team> teams { std::istream_iterator<team>{in},
                          std::istream_iterator<team>{} };
```